# Simple Filesystem/Database Abstraction in Java?

Tags: java, database, text, filesystems, abstract

Basically, I am looking for a simple way to list and access a set of strings in stream form in an abstract manner.  The only issue is that Java's file-accessing API can *only* be used for listing and reading files, and any sort of non-filesystem storage of the data uses a different API.  My question is whether there is some common API I could use (whether included in Java or as an external API) so that I could access both in an abstract manner, but also somewhat efficiently.

Essentially I want a set of lazily streamed text files.  Something like Set might be reasonable, except on a filesystem, you would have to open the text streams even if you don't end up wanting to access that file.

Some sort of api like

```
String[] TextStorage.list()
InputStream TextStorage.open(String elementname);
```

which could abstractly be used to access either filesystems or databases, or some other storage mechanism I invent in the future (maybe fetching something across the internet).

Is there a library which already does this?  Can I do this with the already existing Java API?  Do I need to write this myself?  I'd be surprised if no-one has encountered this problem before, but my google-fu and stackoverflow searches don't seem to find anything.

Comment: Need more clarity.  Confused why you would not write an interface as you described and allow for the implementation to be pluggable via a static `getInstance()` method (or like)?

Comment: The only reason I would not write this interface is to not "reinvent the wheel".  If nothing else exists, it's really not a big deal to write, I just thought that *if* something else exists, why not use it and help keep the world a little more standardized.

Answer (score 0):

you might use HSQL

http://hsqldb.org/